Get Highest high candle between two candle index
I have this function that takes top and bottom values (Candle Index) as inputs and returns the candle index which has highest high between those two candles
// Function to find highest bar index within a specified window
f_find_highest_bar_index(bot, top) =>
    var float hi = 10e-10
    var float lo = 10e10
    var int highestBarIndex = na
    
    bool window = bar_index >= bot and bar_index <= int(top)

    if (window)
        if (high > hi)
            hi := high
            highestBarIndex := bar_index
        
        if (low < lo)
            lo := low

    // Return the highest bar index
    highestBarIndex 

Code works fine and returns 6670 currectly if i pass constant for top value (see image 1)
 top = 6671


But as soon as i pass variable retracementBarIndex in top variable, it returns wrong value 6672, while it should also return 6670. See second image

Cannot quire understand why is this happening?

Your function has two parameters (bot, top), but it uses only one parameter (top).

@Gu5tavo71 bool window = bar_index >= bot and bar_index <= int(top) line has bot variable used

It can't be discerned based on the information provided. There's no demonstration of how retracementBarIndex is determined.
That's where your issue probably is.
